How does this distribution change in "Understanding Diffusion Models: A Unified Perspective"?

In the paper Understanding Diffusion Models: A Unified Perspective, how did we go from equation $(44)$ to $(45)$? I couldn't find the details in the paper. How does the distribtuion for, the expectation change as marked? $q(x_t | x_{t - 1})$ and $p(x_{t - 1} | x_t)$ are Markov processes.
